# Why starting one service does start others (multiple services in one exe)?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

I have a windows service project which consists 5 different services (single exe). In the `Main` method, I am using `ServiceBase.Run([])` to register those:

```
static void Main()
{
    var servicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
    { 
        new ServiceA(),
        new ServiceB(),
        new ServiceC(),
        new ServiceD(),
        new ServiceE(),     
    };

    ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun);
}
```

After installation, i see 5 distinct services in the service manager (services.msc). Nice, but it seems that If I start only a service (say, serviceA), other 4 services also start; though the service manager does not show `started` status against those services(refreshed the view also). If i manually start another service (say, serviceB) and then stop it, it seems that serviceB is no more running, but other 3 services are running.

Any idea why is this happening?

By the way: All services have this pattern:

```
public partial class ServiceA : ServiceBase
{
    private static readonly Timer MyTimer = new Timer(60000);   

    public ServiceA()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // other initializations
        ...
        ...

        MyTimer.Elapsed += <DoSomeTaskFunction>
        MyTimer.AutoReset = true;
        MyTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args])
    {
        myEventLog.WriteEntry("Started...");
        MyTimer.Enabled = true;
        MyTimer.Start();
    }

    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: If the service (control) manager does not show them as started, how do you know they have started?

Comment: What do you mean "started"? Did the other services receive a `Start` event when they shouldn't? Or did their code start executing without receiving without receiving the `Start` event? Do you perhaps start processing in the constructor without waiting for the Start event? Please post the code that handles the `Start` and `Stop` events

Comment: @Christian.K: I know they have started by viewing the event Log.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Code posted.

Comment: I think I found the source of the problem. It is the [`Enabled` property of the `System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.enabled(v=vs.110).aspx) which says setting it `true` is same as `Start()` which was causing the problem. They should have stated it in the description, rather than in the _Remarks_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start working in the constructor of your services. That constructor is called in your `Main` method. That means that your code starts working as soon as the process starts.

It is the `Enabled` property of the `System.Timers.Timer` which says setting it true is same as `Start()` which was causing the problem.

Comment: Found the real cause of the problem. I did not know that `Enabled` of `System.Timers.Timer` also `Start()`s it. MSDN describes it: _true if the Timer should raise the Elapsed event; otherwise, false. The default is false_, which is not clear. Their _Remark_ section clarifies it

Comment: I now see your comments below the question. This is basically what this answer says. I have added this statement of yours, though.

Comment: The BCL team made the mistake of sometimes adding redundant members. For example FileStream.Close and Dispose do exactly the same thing. This leads to lots of confusion and double-calling. The same for Enabled and Start.

Answer (score 0):

To see in the service manager if the rest of services are really running after you started one you need to Refresh the view (context menu).

In regard to your question, there's nothing wrong with your code, and that's how it is supposed to work:

> After you call Run(ServiceBase[]), the Service Control Manager ISSUES
>   START COMMANDS, which result in calls to the OnStart methods in the
>   services. The services are not started until the Start commands are
>   executed.
>   ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6esb073b(v=vs.110).aspx))

To start your services one by one, you need to install them separately and call ***ServiceBase.Run(singleService)*** in each

Comment: The services are really running (verified from event log), but the service manager does not show any status (tried refresh, close+ reopen). If I make 5 different projects and install services, that will definitely work; but what's the point of `Run([])` method then?

Comment: @mshsayem Run([]) starts services at the same time, I guess it is usefull if you need to start a bunch of services at once, esspecialy if they're of the same type and do related things based on some sort of config, and all your services have one .exe file. Question: in which service class is your Main() method located? one of them? all of them? What do you mean by "distinct" services (I'm asking about functionality)?